# Weird WhatsApp message

Tags: word, cipher, story, knowledge, language

Today I found by internet an artist that does commissions. I wanted to get drawn a map for one of my role playing games.

First I tried to call him (there's a lot personal info on the website I found it. Probably not GDPR compliant). He didn't answer his phone.

After that I simply sent him, by WhatsApp, the details of the map I wanted, and asked him what else he needed to fulfill the job.

It took him a while to answer my message but, finally, I received a couple of weird messages and nothing else.

First Message:

> [image: Flags: US, France, Spain, Colombia, Italy, Germany]

Second Message:

> [image: Some hand emojis (hard to describe)]

**Could you help me understand his answer?**

Is he doing the job? If so, what does he need?

---

Second message in Unicode 7.0:

> ️️

---

Hint 1:

> I suspect he didn't answer his phone because he didn't hear the ringtone.

Hint 2:

> This artist had worked with people of all around the world, so he probably knows many languages.

Comment: If you decode both pictures, you get the same bunch of weird text...

Comment: https://shrib.com/#Wierd%20decoded%20text%20from%20both%20pictures

Comment: on the fifth symbol, is the hand pointing one finger up or is that two fingers crossed?

Comment: Two fingers crossed.

Comment: copyable emoji:
``



`✋✋`

Comment: [rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)(VFB pbqrf bs gur nobir syntf: HF SE RF PB VG QR)

Comment: @Mikas: And if you squint, you can see a hidden fresco ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building off @Astralbee's answer:

The message reads:

> **5HOURS**, implying that they are taking the job, but they'll need some time (and, presumably, however much payment they charge for 5 hours worth of work)

To read the message:

> Astralbee is right on the money with sign language**s**, but the important part is the plural. The first message of flags/country codes indicate which sign language to use for each character.
>  ️, in [American Sign Language](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d1/Asl_alphabet_gallaudet.png), indicates **5**.
>  , in [langue des signes française](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_manual_alphabet) or French Sign Language, indicates **H**.
>  , in [Spanish sign language](http://www.deafblind.com/spain.html), indicates **O**.
>  , in [Colombian sign language](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9d/00/7a/9d007abe0a8d57636bdaf2b7eb5765fa.jpg), indicates **U**.
>  , in [Italian sign language](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/b7/05/5f/b7055f911ac3ba6d850d33df447af6c7--deaf-people-deaf-culture.jpg), indicates **R**.
>  ️, in [German sign language](https://www.wpclipart.com/sign_language/German_sign_language_alphabet.png), indicates **S**.

Hint 1 Explanation:

> "I suspect he didn't answer his phone because he didn't hear the ringtone."
>  This is meant to suggest towards deafness and, through that, sign language.

Hint 2 Explanation:

> "This artist had worked with people of all around the world, so he probably knows many languages."
>  This was added after Astralbee made the connection to sign language, but used only American Sign Language in their parsing; it suggests that the first message be used to tell which nation's (most prominent) sign language/manual alphabet should be used for each character.

Answer (score 5):

The message is:

> 5 HOURS

Because:

> I figured he didn't hear the phone because he is deaf and communicates by sign language. Sign languages differ around the world, and the second message is a mix of different sign language alphabets. The first message with the flags is a key to decode them - USA, France, Spain, Columbia, Italy, and Germany. By searching for the sign language alphabet for each country I was able to translate each hand sign.

Comment: What's the first message? Because obviously, 5Y9YR5 means nothing.

Comment: @Masclins updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

> He's busy watching the World Cup. The hand emojis are his reactions to the teams of the respective countries.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please hide your answers inside spoiler tags, to avoid potentially spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves. Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.